# PostgreSQL - displaying the data fetched by the cursor

Tags: postgresql, cursor, fetch

I've successfully created the function that returns the set of cursors, i.e:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_multiple(refcursor, refcursor)
  RETURNS SETOF refcursor AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  OPEN $1 FOR SELECT testtemptable.myid FROM testtemptable;   -- Open the first cursor
  RETURN NEXT $1;                                                                              -- Return the cursor to the caller

  OPEN $2 FOR SELECT testtemptable.name FROM testtemptable;   -- Open the second cursor
  RETURN NEXT $2;                                                                              -- Return the cursor to the caller
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

I call the function and I expect each cursor to return 5 rows, which looks like it's happening. Here is what I do to call it:

```
BEGIN;
select select_multiple('a', 'b');
FETCH ALL IN "a";
FETCH ALL IN "b";
COMMIT;
```

My question is, however, how can I "visualize" the data to verify what's returned?
The "Data Output" tab show nothing at all, and the "Messages" tab shows

```
Query result with 2 rows discarded.
Query result with 5 rows discarded.
Query result with 5 rows discarded.
Query returned successfully with no result in 11 ms.
```

Where have my results been discarded and how can I display them in the "Data Output" tab instead? PostgreSQL version 9.1

Comment: Your script works fine for me in psql.  Are you having problems specifically with pgAdmin3?

Comment: Yes, this is pgAdmin3 specific, I think. I'll try running my scripts in psql if I have to, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your basic problem is that pg_admin won't display results from multi-query blocks.

What you need to do is run each of the statements in order as a separate query.

I.e.

```
Begin; (run)
SELECT * FROM .... ; (run)
FETCH ALL FROM "a"; (run);
etc.
```

Then it will work as expected.

Comment: As a follow up to this, the new "Azure Data Studio" will allow you to return multiple result sets. You can set these types of queries up now and execute in one pass.